# Error: Unsupported DB driver for windows and wamp

Tags: windows, wamp, craftcms

I already config my .env file and db.php file for craft with the same information, before i used 'mysql' as driver but i try it as empty and throws the same error.

db.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Database Configuration
 *
 * All of your system's database connection settings go in here. You can see a
 * list of the available settings in vendor/craftcms/cms/src/config/DbConfig.php.
 *
 * @see craft\config\DbConfig
 */

return [
    'driver' => getenv(''),
    'server' => getenv('localhost'),
    'user' => getenv('root'),
    'password' => getenv('****'),
    'database' => getenv('craftyblog'),
    'schema' => getenv(''),
    'tablePrefix' => getenv(''),
    'port' => getenv('')
];
```

.env

```
# The environment Craft is currently running in ('dev', 'staging', 'production', etc.)
ENVIRONMENT="dev"

# The secure key Craft will use for hashing and encrypting data
SECURITY_KEY="******"

# The database driver that will be used ('mysql' or 'pgsql')
DB_DRIVER=""

# The database server name or IP address (usually this is 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1')
DB_SERVER="localhost"

# The database username to connect with
DB_USER="root"

# The database password to connect with
DB_PASSWORD="****"

# The name of the database to select
DB_DATABASE="craftyblog"

# The database schema that will be used (PostgreSQL only)
DB_SCHEMA=""

# The prefix that should be added to generated table names (only necessary if multiple things are sharing the same database)
DB_TABLE_PREFIX=""

# The port to connect to the database with. Will default to 5432 for PostgreSQL and 3306 for MySQL.
DB_PORT=""

DEFAULT_SITE_URL=""
```

And i'm using WAMP with this versions:

PHP 7.1.16
Apache 2.4.33
MySQL 5.7.21

I expect solve the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your config.php, it appears you're trying to pull in environment variables via [getenv()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php), but you're passing along the actual values you want to use as strings to the `getenv()` function instead of the environment variable name. The values are set in the .env file so it's more portable for collaborative developers.

In that .env file, there isn't have an environment variable set for the database driver, so you can just pass a string to 'driver' instead in config.php.

If you'd like to pull the values from your .env file, pass the variable names as strings for the environment variables in the expected format for `getenv()`, like so:

**config.php**

```
return [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'server' => getenv('DB_SERVER'),
    'user' => getenv('DB_USER'),
    'password' => getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
    'database' => getenv('DB_DATABASE'),
    'schema' => getenv('DB_SCHEMA'),
    'tablePrefix' => getenv('DB_TABLE_PREFIX'),
    'port' => getenv('DB_PORT')
];
```

Your .env file already seems setup for everything, so you should be good to go. However, to use the values from the .env file in the config.php file, you're going to need to pass the variable names as strings. Hope this helps!